# How to compare Azure Tables in different storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I have used `Data Factory` wizard to copy Azure tables from one storage account to another storage account.  Tables are huge with millions of entities and hundreds of partitions.

Now i want to make sure the copied tables are correct. Is there anyway i can compare integrity of tables between 2 storage accounts ?  Does azure has any feature to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in "compare tables" feature. This will be up to you to figure out how to do. I'm guessing you'll need to go partition-by-partition, comparing content. Assuming the content is the same, the order should be the same as well, but it would be an entity-by-entity comparison.

Maybe also consider, on the "write" end of the process, ensuring that you're doing one-for-one item copies?